# PostgreSQL full text search using spanish dictionary to_tsquery does not work in some words

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('spanish', 'sentidos');
```

[image: PostgreSQL full text search using spanish dictionary to_tsquery does not work in some words]

This word returns no lexemes, that means I can't even search for that exact word, nothing matches.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('spanish', 'Esto no tiene sentido ni sentidos') @@ 
to_tsquery('spanish', 'sentidos');
```

returns false, which is completely broken.

Other words work OK

```
SELECT to_tsvector('spanish', 'Esto no tiene pedido ni pedidos') @@
 to_tsquery('spanish', 'pedidos');
```

returns true

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'sentidos' is a stop word in Spanish.  You will find it in `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/spanish.stop`.  This is why it gets removed.  Spanish does seem to have a lot of stop words (2.5 times as many as English), but for all I know this is reasonable.  If you don't agree, you can edit that file to remove words you want kept, taking care to recompute any stored tsvectors and rebuild any indexes afterwards, and document it well so you don't lose your changes when upgrading.  (Or create a fork of the spanish config, to avoid the upgrade problem)

Comment: I can understand it being a stop word in one sense of the word (the verb "feel", very common to say "I feel like this is OK"), but it's also a noun, "the 5 senses" (los cinco sentidos), and my users (education platform) are trying to find info about the five senses and nothing appears.